# how to connect multiple virtual machines in LAN

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware, lan

I am having three virtual machines with different linux distros installed on it(oracle virtualbox).I just wanted to know if there is any way to connect these three machins in LAN.if so how to do it in vmware and virtualbox?

Comment: in virtualbox set networking asa bridged network card and then set ip address from local network

Answer (score 0):

In Vmware you have the option to create another network for your viritual machine (seperate from your local network). This is called Network Address Translation, in short NAT. What it does in simple terms is that it directs traffic from the internet to the correct pc in the local network. Your computer then becomes the router for your viritual machines. It also can act as a DCHP server that gives out IP addresses to your VMs only.

#### Here is an example:

[image: Some network setup with viritual machines]

As you can see here your viritual machines (VM) get internet access from your computer. Your computer acts similary to your normal router. Keep in mind if you want to connect from one of the computers on the local network, you have to do some port forwarding on your computer.

To do this look under network adapter settings in Vmware.

Hope this helped
-Kad

Comment: NAT mode networking is also available in oracle virtual box. It does work the same as way as Kad had described. To make it work, simply choose NAT at the virtual machine network setting.